# books / ways to learn data structures and algorithms?

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I'm a self taught Ruby on Rails engineer, and I'm looking to improve my CS understanding. However, most books about data structures and algorithms are written in Java/C/C++/etc, which I don't know. Is there text on these topics using Ruby? Or do you feel Java is similar enough to Ruby that I could survive through a book?

Is there any recommended text for someone coming from my background?

P.S. Recently I've been looking at Objective C, so I'm not completely blind to statically typed languages.

Comment: I would say that Java/C++ and Ruby are very different. Java/C++: *explicit types*(`int a = 42`, the newest C++ standard has auto keyword that interfere type), classes are not object, bad writibility (you have to write so many words for simple function definition). While Ruby: *no explicit types*(`a = 42`), everything is an object (or at least it can be, after some transformations: block), it has good writibility (aside `end` and `{}` you don't have to write much). So, I would say without even basic C/C++ skills, you will have hard time reading that books.

Comment: You can try this http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/ I think it is easy to read (as current Ruby user), but I may be wrong (as polyglot programmer).

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bunch of books on algorithms that are not tied to specific language. Check

[http://www.amazon.com/Algorithms-Sanjoy-Dasgupta/dp/0073523402](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0073523402)
[http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-Thomas-H-Cormen/dp/0262033844](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844)

I also recommend fundamental, still non-finished classics

[http://www.amazon.com/Computer-Programming-Volumes-1-4A-Boxed/dp/0321751043](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321751043)

Answer (score 2):

If you are jumping into Obj-C it might actually be very worth your time to learn C first. Objective C is very closely related to C minus the odd syntax of Obj-C. In that case you may want to consider K and R which is considered the bible of C to learn that first which will get you started with it to teach you the basics of C and data structures you can later expand on. Also, in case you are learning Objective C to program iOS you may want to be on the cutting edge and learn Swift since Apple is moving to Swift for the future. It is much easier actually and closer to Ruby!

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Yea I am learning objective C to learn iOS development. I think Swift should be easy to learn since it's similar to Ruby. Since the market is still 99.9% objective C I'm going to learn the fundamentals of that first before Swift, since we'll still be in a transition period for at least 1-2 years until you see "Swift Developer" jobs

Comment: @Edmund and @Tom, I don't think it is close to Ruby. As I had short glance at swift user guide 0.94 - http://swift-lang.org/guides/release-0.94/userguide/userguide.html I can say few things: It is more similar to C/C++. It uses types (as C/C++). It has similar `type` construct as Julia - http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/types/#composite-types, or just C's `struct`. It use more functional way of calling things, like neko - http://nekovm.org/specs#hashtables : `<type><function_name>`, e.g. `hadd`(hash add), in the Swift: `strjoin`. It doesn't use `each` but `for`(like Lua or Python)